# Why isn't my Ionic select menu working?

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile, ionic2, user-experience

I am new to Ionic. I want to design a carsharing application. I want to make a "Choose a destination" dropdown menu, with frequent options (like "Here", "Home", or "Anywhere") and a special "Choose a destination" option.

This option would ideally look like another dropdown menu (with the little triangle) and would open a modal with an input that would allow to pick an address (I'm not there yet, I would have to interface with google map or OSM... anyway).

[image: My current UI]

I tried the following code

```
    <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
        Where are you going?    
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Destination</ion-label>
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="destination">
                <ion-option>Here</ion-option>
                <ion-option>Home</ion-option>
                <ion-option>Work</ion-option>
                <ion-option>
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label fixed>Choose a destination</ion-label>
                        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="destination_chosen">
                        </ion-select> 
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-option>
                <ion-option>Anywhere</ion-option>
            </ion-select>   
        </ion-item>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

But it looks like it's not taken into account. What do I do wrong? Is it even possible? If not, would anyone have an idea of a good UX pattern to use in that case?

Comment: Your problem isn't clear. What's not working correctly?

Comment: I want to have a dropdown look on the "Choose a destination" option

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have an dropdown inside a dropdown in ionic, at least not the default component, you'll need to create a custom component for this or maybe use a popover or a modal.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to change the view of the modal to show the actual dropdown menu you want whan that option is selected as if it was a second step. A second different modal would not be ideal since putting a modal inside another modal is not a good UX practice. As it is part of a various-steps process, it won't feel odd.

So, instead of being part of the same view, you would have to createe a second one, should be simple enough with JS or even easier with Angular. A simple ng-show condition should do it.